# Advanced use of Roles in Symfony Security

Tags: symfony, security, fosuserbundle, symfony-security

I am creating a Symfony application where users need to login. I want to use Symfony Security or FOSUserBundle. But I am having trouble deciding how to organize roles.

This is why: there are different destinations. Users can be assigned to one or many destinations. Users can be assigned different roles in different destinations. The hierarchy in different destinations is always the same

I have considered creating roles like 'ROLE_{destination}_{level}'. But I don't want to replicate the hierarchy definition everytime a destination is created. Creating a destination should not require changing the code. Is there a way to read hierarchy in general? I mean, if my User has role 'ROLE_USA_SUPERADMIN' I need to know if that implies 'ROLE_USA_ADMIN'. If I could just check the hierarchy between 'ROLE_SUPERADMIN' and 'ROLE_ADMIN' I would be able to find out.

I have also considered, somehow having different boxes to pull permissions from. Based on what destination is set on session, when I query for 'ROLE_ADMIN' I should get different answers. Any ideas on how to acomplish that?

Comment: There is a RoleHierarchy service that allows navigating the role hierarchy.  As far as setting roles based on the current route/session, a custom UserProvider could do the trick.  But if you have not already, take a look at security voters. They might suggest a different approach.